# Make virtual machine work on local network

Tags: networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I run VMware Workstation on Windows 10 machine that is connected to network via ethernet adapter that has defined static IP address 192.168.103 . Network has DHCP server enabled on wifi router that offers IP addresses according to form 192.168.1.XXX except 192.168.103.

I need to create virtual machine that should be connected to home network and get IP from my home router.

I have selected NAT in network connection:

[image]

And my machine got strange address not from my home network:
192.168.52.139  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.52.255

I changed to Bridged connection:

[image]

Got error in my Ubuntu virtual machine 'activation of network connection failed' and it looks like my virtual machine haven't got IP address.

How to configure virtual machine adapter in order make it work in my home network?

Comment: Try unchecking "Replicate physical network connection state "   .   See:  https://www.conceptworks.io/en/knowledge-base/vmware-65-rc1-workstation-replicate-physical-network-connection-state/#:~:text=Replicate%20physical%20network%20connection%20state%20%E2%80%94%20Select%20if%20the%20virtual%20machine,IP%20address%20is%20automatically%20renewed.

Comment: Try to remove your network adapter in the VM and re-add it again.

Comment: Please let us know what you are trying. I use VMware Workstation V16 and have this working here with Bridged Networking (and getting the proper address).